# Unable to bridge network to qemu (libvirt) guest

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, qemu

I am running a virtual machine with virt-manager on my Ubuntu 16.04 server and am trying to get the guest into the same network as the host.

I have attempted to follow [these directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking) however I ended up with a guest which can ping the host, but not the internet.

**Host Config**

```
host$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto enp3s0
#iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
iface enp3s0 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports enp3s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0

host$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br1             8000.002590606dae       no              enp3s0
docker0         8000.024255cb1799       no              veth12ab6bb
                                                        veth132d7f2
                                                        veth167e73b
                                                        veth3538eea
                                                        veth35cae89
                                                        veth434db1b
                                                        veth794ed99
                                                        veth90e96b0
                                                        vethc19adf6
                                                        vethc2669ae
                                                        vethc3b9c37
                                                        vethe62f5fe
virbr0          8000.525400263616       yes             virbr0-nic

host$ ip address show br1
89: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:60:6d:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.42/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global br1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe60:6dae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

host$ ip address show enp3s0
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:60:6d:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**Guest Config**

From `/etc/libvirt/qemu/testvm.xml` on the host:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:ad:ab:0c'/>
      <source bridge='br1'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

In the guest, the `ens3` network interface is configured for DHCP and is not getting an IP address. The guest is using netplan.

Comment: Is there even a DHCP server on your local network? We see that you configured the host's IP address manually instead of via DHCP.

Comment: There is a DHCP server. Can you elaborate on where you see that please? I experimented with statically configuring the IP on the host when I was first setting up the bridge, but was having trouble with it and went back to DHCP.

Comment: You posted: `iface enp3s0 inet manual` Of course, that has no effect after you added it to bridge `br1`. So...

Comment: Ah sure, one of the guides I was following set that to prevent the interface from causing problems accidentally. I have tried with and without that line.